# How do I hide the title on a specific node?

Tags: 7, entities, theming

How can I hide the title on a specific node?

I have tried the following three modules, but none of them do what I'd like.

1. [Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title)
2. [Exclude node title](http://drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title)
3. [Automatic Node titles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)

I added field_hide_title to the page content type, the code in `hook_preprocess_node()` function. It can't work fine.

[image: screenshot]

The value shown from `print_r($vars['node'])` is the following:

```
stdClass Object(
  [vid] => 4
  [uid] => 1
  [title] => search_material
  [log] => 
  [status] => 1
  [comment] => 1
  [promote] => 0
  [sticky] => 0
  [nid] => 4
  [type] => page
  [language] => zh-hant
  [created] => 1339055801
  [changed] => 1339727555
  [tnid] => 0
  [translate] => 0
  [revision_timestamp] => 1339727555
  [revision_uid] => 1
  [body] => Array(
    [und] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
        [value] =>
        [summary] =>
        [format] => php_code
      )
    )
  )
  [field_hide_title] => Array(
    [und] => Array(
      [0] => Array([value] => 1)
    )
  )
  [rdf_mapping] => Array(
    [rdftype] => Array([0] => foaf:Document)
    [title] => Array(
      [predicates] => Array([0] => dc:title)
    )
    [created] => Array(
      [predicates] => Array(
        [0] => dc:date
        [1] => dc:created
      )
      [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
      [callback] => date_iso8601
    )
    [changed] => Array(
      [predicates] => Array([0] => dc:modified)
      [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
      [callback] => date_iso8601
    )
    [body] => Array(
      [predicates] => Array([0] => content:encoded)
    )
    [uid] => Array(
      [predicates] => Array([0] => sioc:has_creator)
      [type] => rel
    )
    [name] => Array(
      [predicates] => Array([0] => foaf:name)
    )
    [comment_count] => Array(
      [predicates] => Array([0] => sioc:num_replies)
      [datatype] => xsd:integer
    )
    [last_activity] => Array(
      [predicates] => Array ([0] => sioc:last_activity_date)
      [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
      [callback] => date_iso8601
    )
  )
  [cid] => 0
  [last_comment_timestamp] => 1339055801
  [last_comment_name] =>
  [last_comment_uid] => 1
  [comment_count] => 0
  [name] => admin
  [picture] => 0
  [data] => b:0;
  [entity_view_prepared] => 1
)
```

============================================================
UPDATE:

## but I found one thing. before I change the title to NULL, the title has been displayed out...

print_r($vars) in mytheme_preprocess_page function:

[summary] => [format] => php_code ) ) ) [field_hide_title] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 1 ) ) ) [rdf_mapping] => Array ( [rdftype] => Array ( [0] => foaf:Document ) [title] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:title ) ) [created] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:date [1](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) => dc:created ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) [changed] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:modified ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) [body] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => content:encoded ) ) [uid] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:has_creator ) [type] => rel ) [name] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => foaf:name ) ) [comment_count] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:num_replies ) [datatype] => xsd:integer ) [last_activity] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:last_activity_date ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) ) [cid] => 0 [last_comment_timestamp] => 1339039221 [last_comment_name] => [last_comment_uid] => 1 [comment_count] => 0 [name] => admin [picture] => 0 [data] => b:0; [entity_view_prepared] => 1 ) )

Comment: Do you wan't to hide the title for all nodes or just one specific?

Comment: I don't want to modify template because it will cause effect all node.

Comment: You can change the template per node TYPE.  Why not just use CSS? `.page-node-NID .page-title { display: none;}`

Comment: IMHO..doing it via template.php and css for every node is a good idea if the node you want to hide the title is specific. But if you are creating a new node constantly and some of it should not display node title then you need to update your code regularly which will point to maintenance issue. You will ended up having long code. 

This question is related to my task before which I ended up creating a cck field so the editors of the site can tick the checkbox if he dont want to appear the Title or Headline for some reason.

Comment: Doing it via CSS is especially recommendable if you care for site ranking. To my knowledge, titles in header tags are one of the strongest ranking boosters.

Comment: Using `print_r($vars['node']);` in `function yourTheme_preprocess_node(&$vars)` may return you all the fields and non-cck in that specific node.

Comment: @ninjascorner- but I found one thing. before I change the title to NULL, the title has been displayed out...

Comment: Sorry typo error in my code it should be `$vars['node']->title = NULL;` and not `$vars['node']->title == NULL;` Sorry about that.

Comment: @ninjascorner- of course. but as my said.  before I change the title to NULL, the title has been displayed out...

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "the title has been displayed out"?

Comment: I just tried here in my local and the above is working. Did you configure your cck field to something in my screenshot below?

Comment: Oh wait are you in Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Comment: @ninjascorner- I use Drupal 7. I don't have the cck field like you post.

Comment: Ok... I will setup a D7 and I will get back to you later for the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a cck field(checkbox/boolean) for that will act as a flag. So you can have a dynamic option if you want to hide the node or not.

Pseudo code:

In template.php

```
function yourtTheme_process_page(&$variables) {
  if($variables['node']->field_hide_title['und'][0]['value']) {
    $variables['title'] = NULL;
  }
}
```

Haven't try this code but I think this will work.

EDIT: Added screenshot of a new field
[image]

This should be the value of your cck
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS.

Each individual node will have a specific class on the `<body>` tag of the page, which will allow you to target your specific node.

For example, say you're trying to hide the title on node 69, it would look like the following:

```
.page-node-69 .page-title { 
  display: none;
}
```

for node 150 it would look like this:

```
.page-node-150 .page-title { 
  display: none;
}
```

You might have to tweak it depending on your theme, and you might have to more specifically target the page title (i.e. `h1.page-title`) just in case there is more specificity further up the cascade.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could add something like this into your template.php:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$node) {
    // check if it's the node of interest
    if($node['title'] == 'your-specific-node-title') {
       // set the title to NULL so nothing is rendered
       $node['title'] = NULL; 
    }
}
```

As [chapabu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3119/chapabu) suggested it might be a better idea to check the node nid instead of the title:

```
if($node['nid'] == 'your-node-nid') {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could specify why downvoting?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but processing the node based on NID is probably more reliable than title.  I shall give this an upvote to counteract the downvote :-)

Comment: @Chapabu - Yes of course the node id makes more sense than the title.

Comment: It seems not convenient. :(

Comment: So it works...but it's not convenient for you to implement?

Comment: @user6919 - "it seems not convenient" and why is that? It would hide the node title for a specific node, wasn't that the question?

Comment: @KristerAndersson, It can hide the title. but the if statement will grow up when more nodes need to hide title.

Comment: Will it be one specific node TYPE that needs the title hiding (for example: will you want titles hidden on ALL Basic Pages, but not on Articles)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS on the title is a class of title and ID of page-title, so my CSS needs to be

```
.page-node-69 #page.title {
   display: none; 
}
```

for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 9, the title is a block. You can edit the block to exclude showing it on specific pages. If I recall, that's a core feature and not a plugin we're using. =)